# Letting a bot play a youtube video in a voice channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am trying to let a bot play a youtube video but only sound in a voice channel if you type a command. I already have a command that lets the bot connect to a voice channel

```
client.on("ready", () => {
  const channel = client.channels.cache.get("922159751759011910");
  if(!channel) return console.error("Channel non-existent");
  channel.join().then(connection => {

    console.log("Connected");
  }).catch(e => {

    console.error(e)
  })
})
```

But I don't know how to let it play  a youtube video. How do I do this?

Comment: I advise you upgrade to discord.js v13, it's predicted that v12 is going to break soon

Comment: I already am on version 13

Comment: That's impossible, `.join()` is not in v13

Comment: You are absolutely right, I didnt look at the right place

Comment: I just updated it, but it doesnt seem to work. it gives an error: ```Error: Cannot find module 'node:events```

Comment: @LarsdeKooter You sure you're using the correct node version? You need at least node v16 to use djs v13

Comment: @UnidentifiedX see now. My node is v12.16.1

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [discord-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-player). It has some links to example projects using it, if you want to see how they implement this functionality.